# How to choose the features that describe x% of all information in data while using Incremental principal components analysis (IPCA)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I'd like to use the [Incremental principal components analysis](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA) (IPCA) to reduce my feature space such that it contains x% of information.

I would use the `sklearn.decomposition.IncrementalPCA(n_components=None, whiten=False, copy=True, batch_size=None)`
I can leave the `n_components=None` so that it works on all the features that I have.

But later once the whole data set is analyzed. 
How do I select the features that represent x% of data and how do I create a `transform()` for those features number of features.

This idea taken from this [question.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/how-many-dimensions-to-reduce-to-when-doing-pca)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the percentage of explained variance from each of the components of your PCA using `explained_variance_ratio_`. For example in the iris dataset, the first 2 principal components account for 98% of the variance in the data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import decomposition
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
pca = decomposition.IncrementalPCA()
pca.fit(X)
pca.explaned_variance_ratio_

#array([ 0.92461621,  0.05301557,  0.01718514,  0.00518309])
```